# Is it possible to set a variable equal to a function without using an enclosure?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, you can set a variable equal to a method like this:

```
variable = function () { alert("My name is bob"); };
```

Or like this:

```
function SayMyName() {
   alert("My name is bob");
}
variable = SayMyName;
```

You can also enclose a function with arguments like so:

```
function SayMyName(name) {
   alert("My name is "+ name);
}
variable = function () { SayMyName("bob"); };
```

But trying to store a variable the following way will call the function, not store it as a variable:

```
function SayMyName(name) {
   alert("My name is "+ name);
}
variable = SayMyName("bob");
```

There was a clever way you used to be able to work around this by using [callee][1], but callee is depreciated and won't work on most modern browsers.

Is there any way to set a variable equal to a function with arguments *without* using an enclosure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `bind` method to fix some parameters

```
var variable = SayMyName.bind(null, "bob");
```

However, this does not work in IE <= 8 so you would have to use a similar replacement or polyfil in tha case.

Comment: +1 for actually answering my question and not using enclosures.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you use a nested anonymous function for this?

```
var variable = function(name) {
  return function() {
    alert('My name is ' + name);
  };
};
```

Calling it yields your desired result:

```
var test = variable('bob');
test(); // Alerts "My name is bob"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a function, like:

```
function SayMyName(x) { return function() { alert("My name is Bob.");}};

var x = SayMyName('bob');
x();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = (function sayMyName(name) {
    return alert('My name is: ' + name);
});
name('Mike');​​​​​
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ToyProgram{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String funcCallVar = aFunc();
        System.out.println(funcCallVar);
    }
    public static String aFunc(){
        String aVariable = "yes you can set a variale equal to a function";
        return aVariable;
    }
}
```